# Efficiency of Gradient Ascent vs Hill Climbing

Tags: algorithm, optimization, gradient-descent, hill-climbing

I'm running both gradient ascent and hill climbing on a landscape to assess which one can reach the greatest height in less steps. The outcome of my test is that hill climbing always manages to reach greater heights in less increments in comparison to gradient ascent. What's reason behind this. Because I thought gradient ascent would be more efficient. Does anyone have experience with these algorithms that may have something to say about the outcome.

Thank you.

Comment: This *might* get (better) answers at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Please post your implementations of the two algorithms. Also, try to describe your data (or post a screenshot if applicable).